# Applying over a row of a data frame

Tags: r, loops, apply

I want to use lapply over a set of rows of a dataframe. However when I follow the examples I've seen it seems to give me an error

EDIT: I preferentially want to use lapply instead of apply because I have a giant piece of code based on lapply and I remembered that I needed to use two lists of values in the loop rather than just one.

```
place <- c("cal","ny")
salary <- c(21000,30000)

databox <- data.frame(place, salary)


dataframeFun<-function()
 {

 lapply(databox[,c('place','salary')],1,function(x)
  {dfList<-list('place'=place,'salary'=salary)})} 



dataframeFun()

Error in match.fun(FUN) : '1' is not a function, character or symbol
```

Comment: `apply` works on matrices. If you give it a data frame, it converts it to a matrix before doing anything else, which might not be great for your use case. You can use a `for` loop instead to fix this. Your other problem is that your anonymous function is a function of `x`, but it doesn't reference `x` internally, you just use the `place` and `salary` variables defined in the global environment - this is why you get the entire `place` and `salary` in the output.  All that said, you seem to be looking for `split`: `dfList = split(databox, 1:nrow(databox))`

Comment: The ",1" should be somewhere else. Since it is the 2nd parameter `lapply()`, believes this is the function to use.

Comment: `lapply` on a data frame will work on columns, not rows. There is no place for `, 1` in `lapply()`.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense anymore. `lapply` won't let you "use two lists of values" any more than `apply`. Use a `for` loop or `map` for that. Or `mapply`. If you need help with that, you should edit your question to illustrate the "two lists of values".